# Создание теста NUnit/Xunit

Tags: c#, nunit, xunit

Пробовал сделать это через GPT но не помогло(была ошибка "4 Не запущен"), возможно из-за того, что там старые инструкции(не знаю). Нужно написать 3 NUnit, или Xunit тесты к этой проге:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

// Main Application Class
public class TableReservationApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReservationManagerClass m = new ReservationManagerClass();
        m.AddRestaurantMethod("A", 10);
        m.AddRestaurantMethod("B", 5);

        Console.WriteLine(m.BookTable("A", new DateTime(2023, 12, 25), 3)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(m.BookTable("A", new DateTime(2023, 12, 25), 3)); // False
    }
}

// Reservation Manager Class
public class ReservationManagerClass
{
    // res
    public List<RestaurantClass> Restaurants { get; private set; }

    public ReservationManagerClass()
    {
        Restaurants = new List<RestaurantClass>();
    }

    // Add Restaurant Method
    public void AddRestaurantMethod(string name, int tableCount)
    {
        try
        {
            RestaurantClass restaurant = new RestaurantClass();
            restaurant.Name = name;
            restaurant.Tables = new RestaurantTableClass[tableCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < tableCount; i++)
            {
                restaurant.Tables[i] = new RestaurantTableClass();
            }

            Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Load Restaurants From
    // File
    private void LoadRestaurantsFromFileMethod(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var parts = line.Split(',');

                if (parts.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(parts[1], out int tableCount))
                {
                    AddRestaurantMethod(parts[0], tableCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid line: {line}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    //Find All Free Tables
    public List<string> FindAllFreeTables(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> freeTables = new List<string>();

            foreach (var restaurant in Restaurants)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.Tables.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!restaurant.Tables[i].IsBooked(date))
                    {
                        freeTables.Add($"{restaurant.Name} - Table {i + 1}");
                    }
                }
            }

            return freeTables;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public bool BookTable(string restaurantName, DateTime date, int tableNumber)
    {
        foreach (var restaurant in Restaurants)
        {
            if (restaurant.Name == restaurantName)
            {
                if (tableNumber < 0 || tableNumber >= restaurant.Tables.Length)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid table number");//Invalid table number
                }

                return restaurant.Tables[tableNumber].Book(date);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Restaurant not found");//Restaurant not found
    }

    public void SortRestaurantsByAvailabilityForUsersMethod(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            bool swapped;

            do
            {
                swapped = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < Restaurants.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    int avTc = CountAvailableTablesForRestaurantClassAndDateTimeMethod(Restaurants[i], date);
                    int avTn = CountAvailableTablesForRestaurantClassAndDateTimeMethod(Restaurants[i + 1], date);

                    if (avTc < avTn)
                    {
                        // Swap restaurants
                        var temp = Restaurants[i];
                        Restaurants[i] = Restaurants[i + 1];
                        Restaurants[i + 1] = temp;
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (swapped);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // count available tables in a restaurant
    public int CountAvailableTablesForRestaurantClassAndDateTimeMethod(RestaurantClass restaurant, DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var table in restaurant.Tables)
            {
                if (!table.IsBooked(date))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

// Restaurant Class
public class RestaurantClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }//name
    public RestaurantTableClass[] Tables { get; set; }// tables
}

// // Table Class
public class RestaurantTableClass
{
    private List<DateTime> bookedDates;

    public RestaurantTableClass()
    {
        bookedDates = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    // book
    public bool Book(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            if (bookedDates.Contains(date))
            {
                return false;
            }
            //add to bd
            bookedDates.Add(date);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // is booked
    public bool IsBooked(DateTime date)
    {
        return bookedDates.Contains(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"4 Не запущен"` - установите TestAdapter.

Comment: NUnit3TestAdapter установлен

Comment: тут не нужен чат жпт. Просто создайте шаблонный проект Xunit, зареференсите первоначальный проект, и посмотрите пример того как в Xunit тесты пишется. Достаточно сделать публичный класс с публичным методом